# Adding and removing stylesheets with webpack

Tags: javascript, css, webpack

I'm interested in using WebPack for my SPA (I haven't used it before), which will have several pages, each with their own bundle of JS, CSS and HTML.

Firstly, is there a way to remove stylesheets that aren't being used using webpack? From a look at the [documentation](http://webpack.github.io/docs/stylesheets.html), it seems that there isn't. For example, say I have a `#wrapper` div that needs to have a `width: auto` for most pages, but a `width: 100%` for a certain page that needs to be full screen. If my modules just `require()` their stylesheets, then they will all keep being added to the HTML, and the last one to be loaded will have control over the `width`, whereas I want just the current page's stylesheet to be loaded. Is there any way to remove stylesheets using webpack? Or is there a better solution to this problem?

In addition, does webpack have a callback for stylesheets? If I need to run some code only when the css has loaded (I mean the onload callback has fired, not just when the tag is added to the html), is there a proper way of doing it?